# Get facebook news feed using graph api v2.4 and above

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ok I have read it in the doc
[facebook developer docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5)

It says to get news feed the url must append '/home' for which 'read_stream' scope is required and it also says

> The read_stream permission is only available for apps using Graph API version v2.3 or older.

And I also know the feeds for pages is available with facebook page plug-in.

Now my question is, is there still any possibility or hack to get the news feed using graph api.

For me the url should be:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/home/feed?limit=n&accesstoken=xyz&fields=actions,comments,from,message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `user_posts` permission. Of course you don´t get the whole stream anymore, only posts of the user and posts from his friends on his wall. There is no way to get the whole feed anymore, for privacy reasons.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog